# Convert $\int^{2}_{-2}\int^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int^{4}_{x^2+y^2}\;x\;dz\;dy\;dx$ to cylindrical or spherical coordinates and evaluate.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Convert $\int^{2}_{-2}\int^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int^{4}_{x^2+y^2}\;x\;dz\;dy\;dx$ to cylindrical or spherical coordinates and evaluate.

To do this I first evaluated the innermost integral so that I could get a double integral and convert the limits to cylindrical coordinates like this:

$$\int^{2}_{-2}\int^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int^{4}_{x^2+y^2}\;x\;dz\;dy\;dx=\int^{2}_{-2}\int^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}xz\;|^{4}_{x^2+y^2}\;dy\;dx$$

This gives the double integral:

$$\int^{2}_{-2}\int^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}4x-x^3+xy^2\;dy\;dx$$

I then converted this to cylindrical and found that:

$$0 \le r \le 3$$

$$0\le \theta \le 2\pi$$

So rewriting the integral I got:

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{3}_{0}(4r\cos\theta-\cos^3\theta+cos\theta \sin^2\theta)r\;dr\;d\theta$$

Did I do the conversion correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a slight error.
If you solve the equation for $y$:
$$x^2 +y^2 = 4$$

Gives you:

$$y = \sqrt{4-x^2}$$
$$y = -\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

**This function describes a circle of radius $2$, not $3$.**

Therefore $0 \le r \le 2$ when converting to cylindrical coordinates and:

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{2}_{0}(4r\cos\theta-\cos^3\theta+cos\theta \sin^2\theta)r\;dr\;d\theta$$

Comment: Wow, not sure how I snuck that three into there.  Everything else looks good?

Comment: @inquisitor everything else is good

Comment: Woohoo!  I thin I'm finally starting to get this!  Thanks for your help